# In asp.net application, while uploading a file, getting access denied error

Tags: asp.net

Although we have full access to the path,still it is showing the error access to the path is denied, Could you please help in resolving the issue.
Also, look the text in bold and italic.

Server Error in '/Global' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Access to the path 'F:\www\Global\Reports\2017-05-30, VDA_6.3_ABC_Vers_R_13_englisch.xlsm' is denied. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'F:\www\Global\Reports\2017-05-30, VDA_6.3_ABC_Vers_R_13_englisch.xlsm' is denied. 

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user. 

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'F:\www\Global\Reports\2017-05-30, VDA_6.3_ABC_Vers_R_13_englisch.xlsm' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7725671
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +1162
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +61
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +55
   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +99
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.SaveAs(String filename) +23
   webpages_Audit_Schedule_upload.append_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ***f:\CBC_CODE\CBC\Orange\CBC\webpages\Schedule\upload.aspx***.cs:1666
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8762; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8762
```

Comment: What do you mean by "we have full access to the path"? Did you try providing access to that folder for the account (Ex: Network Service) under which your Asp.Net application is running?

Comment: Siva Gopal, thanks for your answer but i couldnot get your point.
To make it more clear,What i mean to say that we have published the code in F drive of the server and we have access to the F drive and its subfolders but while uploading the file to F:\www\Global\Reports\ we are getting access denied error although we have full access to this path also.

Comment: Permission to browse the folder for "us" is not same as permission to browse that folder for "Asp.Net" account. So in IIS check under which account your application is running? Go to IIS, locate your application and on right side click "Basic Settings..." and check "Application Pool:" field. Then go to IIS Root > Application Pools > Select the application pool you see in previous step > Click "Advance Settings" on right side > check "Identity" field under "Process Model". And for that account grant access to the folder where access denied and give it a try.